# encryption/decryption by Aes not working

Tags: java, android

this code encryption/decryption dynamic data that entered by user:

```
private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
    private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";
    public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
        byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key) throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {
        byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);
    }

    public  byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidParameterSpecException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        return cipherText;
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        plainText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        return plainText;
    }

    private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
        System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }
```

but for some data (example : u8/OgSllm2agXlDrGcdqWg== ) decryption is not working and execution catch:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

or for some data get different error , example : SmQ0YMiq+SHn34m8h3gWw== 
 get this error  :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this code and download library commons-codec-1.11-bin from the below link and add it to build path**

[enter link description here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi)

**Java Code:**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AES {
    public static String encrypt(String key, String initVector, String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            System.out.println("encrypted string: "
                    + Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted));

            return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String key, String initVector, String encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

            return new String(original);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
        String initVector = "RandomInitVector"; // 16 bytes IV

        System.out.println(decrypt(key, initVector,
                encrypt(key, initVector, "Hello World")));
    }
}
```